# Javascript keep focusing and click element

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger div hover state and click trash icon with javascript.
Trash icon invisible , when mouse come to on parent div , its getting visible.
I tried so many times but nothing happend :(

My code here ;

```
document.getElementsByClassName("table_body-row table_row")[1].focus(); 
document.getElementsByClassName("table-hover_icon icon-link")[1].click();
```

How Can i keep focusing hover and click ?

[image: Mouse out]

[image]

[image]

If i get mouse manually on div , and exucute code in developers console it working.

Comment: `focus` and `mouseover` are not the same.

Comment: @connexo but after execute document.getElementsByClassName("table_body-row table_row")[1].focus();  I can get information of edit and trash div

Answer (score 0):

keep the div and icon on same position and on "mouseover" change the z-index of icon to > 1.

```
<div>
    <div onmouseover = "change(2)" style="top : 0; left : 0;"> </div>
    <div style="top : 0; left : 0;" id = "icon"> some icon <div>
</div>

function change(index) {
   document.querySelector("#icon").style.zIndex = index;
}
```